Creating and fixing PDF with margings, and text style in reportlab
I'm having an issue creating a report using ReportLab in Python.
I'm using a JSON file from an AWS S3 bucket. Here is a sample of the information:
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A1
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import cm

    
company_info = [
    {'title': 'What were Harley\'s total sales for Q3?', 
     'context': 'Harley\'s total sales for Q3 were /n **$15 million**, representing a **10% increase** compared to Q2.'},
    {'title': 'Which region showed the highest sales?', 
     'context': 'The **North American region** showed the highest sales, contributing **$8 million** to the total.'},
    {'title': 'What was the percentage increase in sales for the European market?', 
     'context': 'The **European market** experienced a /n **12% increase** in sales, totaling **$4 million** for Q3.'},
    {'title': 'Did Harley\'s introduce any new products in Q3?', 
     'context': ('In Q3, Harley\'s made a significant impact with the introduction of **two new products** that have been well-received by the market. '
                 'The **Harley Davidson X1** is a cutting-edge motorcycle designed with advanced technology and performance enhancements, catering to the evolving needs of enthusiasts. '
                 'Alongside, the **Harley Davidson Pro Series** offers a range of high-performance accessories aimed at enhancing the riding experience. '
                 'These new products have been introduced in response to customer feedback and market trends, reflecting Harley\'s commitment to innovation and quality. '
                 'The product launches have been supported by comprehensive marketing efforts, including promotional events and digital campaigns, which have effectively generated excitement and increased consumer interest.')},
    {'title': 'What was the impact of the new product launches on sales?', 
     'context': ('The recent product launches had a substantial impact on Harley\'s sales performance for Q3. The introduction of the **Harley Davidson X1** and the **Harley Davidson Pro Series** '
                 'contributed an additional **$2 million** in revenue, accounting for approximately **13%** of the total Q3 sales. '
                 'These new products not only boosted overall sales but also enhanced Harley\'s market position by attracting new customers and increasing repeat purchases. '
                 'The successful integration of these products into the company\'s existing lineup demonstrates Harley\'s ability to innovate and adapt to market demands. '
                 'Ongoing customer feedback and sales data will continue to inform product development and marketing strategies, ensuring that Harley\'s maintains its competitive edge and meets consumer expectations.')},
]

I'm using this code to generate the report, and I want to include a background image.
def create_report(company_info, image_path, output_pdf_path):
    # Define margins
    top_margin = 12 * cm
    bottom_margin = 8 * cm
    left_margin = 2 * cm
    right_margin = 2 * cm
    
    # Create a canvas object
    c = canvas.Canvas(output_pdf_path, pagesize=A1)
    
    # Draw the background image
    c.drawImage(image_path, 0, 0, width=A1[0], height=A1[1])
    
    # Define text properties
    font_size = 18
    c.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", font_size)
    
    # Calculate y position
    y_position = A1[1] - top_margin
    
    # Write the content
    for i, item in enumerate(company_info):
        question = item.get('title', '')
        answer = item.get('context', '')
        
        # Write question number and question
        c.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", font_size)
        c.drawString(left_margin, y_position, f'{i + 1}. {question}')
        y_position -= font_size + 10  # Adjust for line spacing
        
        # Write answer
        c.setFont("Helvetica", font_size)
        c.drawString(left_margin, y_position, answer)
        y_position -= 2 * font_size + 30  # Adjust for space between question and answer
        
        # Check if y position is below the bottom margin
        if y_position < bottom_margin:
            c.showPage()
            c.drawImage(image_path, 0, 0, width=A1[0], height=A1[1])
            y_position = A1[1] - top_margin
            c.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", font_size)  # Reapply font settings for new page

    # Save the PDF
    c.save()


bg = 'bg_temp.jpg'  # Path to your background image
output_pdf_path = 'report_harleys.pdf'  # Path where the PDF will be saved

create_report(company_info, bg, output_pdf_path)

I haven't yet been able to achieve the following:

Justify the text (both the title and the context) so that it does not extend beyond the right margin of the page.
Ensure that new lines specified by \n and bold text indicated by ** in my JSON are correctly reflected in the PDF.

Here is what I'm currently getting:

I would like it to look something like this:

Notice how with there a \n we have a new line and text between ** are bold? reference with the first item of the company info.
What might I be missing? I've tried numerous tutorials but haven't achieved the desired outcome.

why you do not use FPDF? it is more simple and stable

I have tried my best,

and I have gotten a huge help from ChatGPT.

i tried to make each ** text ** bold, but the problem is that i can not change the font each time i want bold, so ChatGPT added new line to each word needs bold,

from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A1
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.units import cm



def draw_wrapped_text(c, text, x, y, max_width):
    is_bold = False  # To track whether the text should be bold
    start_pos = 0
    y_offset = 1.2 * cm

    while start_pos < len(text):
        # Find the next bold markers
        if '**' in text[start_pos:]:
            bold_start = text.find('**', start_pos)
            bold_end = text.find('**', bold_start + 2)

            if bold_start > start_pos:
                # Draw text before the bold marker
                normal_text = text[start_pos:bold_start].replace('\n', ' ')
                y = draw_text_segment(c, normal_text, x, y, max_width, is_bold=False)

            # Draw the bold text
            bold_text = text[bold_start + 2:bold_end].replace('\n', ' ')
            y = draw_text_segment(c, bold_text, x, y, max_width, is_bold=True)

            # Update the position after the bold text
            start_pos = bold_end + 2
        else:
            # Draw the remaining text as normal
            normal_text = text[start_pos:].replace('\n', ' ')
            y = draw_text_segment(c, normal_text, x, y, max_width, is_bold=False)
            break

    return y  # Return the updated y position after the text is drawn


def draw_text_segment(c, text, x, y, max_width, is_bold):
    lines = []
    current_line = ""
    
    font = "Helvetica-Bold" if is_bold else "Helvetica"
    c.setFont(font, 12)

    for word in text.split():
        if c.stringWidth(current_line + " " + word, font, 12) <= max_width:
            current_line += " " + word
        else:
            lines.append(current_line.strip())
            current_line = word
    
    lines.append(current_line.strip())

    for line in lines:
        c.drawString(x, y, line)
        y -= 1.2 * cm

    return y

# Create the canvas object
c = canvas.Canvas("company_report.pdf", pagesize=A1)
width, height = A1

company_info = [
    {'title': "What were Harley's total sales for Q3?", 
     'context': "Harley's total sales for Q3 were \n **$15 million**, representing a **10% increase** compared to Q2."},
    
    {'title': "Which region showed the highest sales?", 
     'context': "The **North American region** showed the highest sales, contributing **$8 million** to the total."},
    
    {'title': "What was the percentage increase in sales for the European market?", 
     'context': "The **European market** experienced a \n **12% increase** in sales, totaling **$4 million** for Q3."},
    
    {'title': "Did Harley's introduce any new products in Q3?", 
     'context': ("In Q3, Harley's made a significant impact with the introduction of **two new products** that have been well-received by the market. "
                 "The **Harley Davidson X1** is a cutting-edge motorcycle designed with advanced technology and performance enhancements, catering to the evolving needs of enthusiasts. "
                 "Alongside, the **Harley Davidson Pro Series** offers a range of high-performance accessories aimed at enhancing the riding experience. "
                 "These new products have been introduced in response to customer feedback and market trends, reflecting Harley's commitment to innovation and quality. "
                 "The product launches have been supported by comprehensive marketing efforts, including promotional events and digital campaigns, which have effectively generated excitement and increased consumer interest.")},
    
    {'title': "What was the impact of the new product launches on sales?", 
     'context': ("The recent product launches had a substantial impact on Harley's sales performance for Q3. The introduction of the **Harley Davidson X1** and the **Harley Davidson Pro Series** "
                 "contributed an additional **$2 million** in revenue, accounting for approximately **13%** of the total Q3 sales. "
                 "These new products not only boosted overall sales but also enhanced Harley's market position by attracting new customers and increasing repeat purchases. "
                 "The successful integration of these products into the company's existing lineup demonstrates Harley's ability to innovate and adapt to market demands. "
                 "Ongoing customer feedback and sales data will continue to inform product development and marketing strategies, ensuring that Harley's maintains its competitive edge and meets consumer expectations.")}
]

# Start writing the content
y = height - 2 * cm  # Initial y position

for item in company_info:
    title = item['title']
    context = item['context']
    
    # Draw the title in bold
    c.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", 16)
    c.drawString(2 * cm, y, title)
    y -= 1.5 * cm  # Space between title and context
    
    # Draw the context with wrapped text
    y = draw_wrapped_text(c, context, 2 * cm, y, width - 4 * cm)
    y -= 2 * cm  # Space between entries

# Save the PDF
c.save()


I hope you use another library like FPDF2, it is better than this lib, unless you want features in this library only, but I do not see special features here.
and this is using FPDF2

pip install fpdf2

this is the code using FPDF2
i have written a lot of comments to help you understand everything in the code:
from fpdf import FPDF




company_info = [
    {'title': "What were Harley's total sales for Q3?", 
     'context': "Harley's total sales for Q3 were \n **$15 million**, representing a **10% increase** compared to Q2."},
    
    {'title': "Which region showed the highest sales?", 
     'context': "The **North American region** showed the highest sales, contributing **$8 million** to the total."},
    
    {'title': "What was the percentage increase in sales for the European market?", 
     'context': "The **European market** experienced a \n **12% increase** in sales, totaling **$4 million** for Q3."},
    
    {'title': "Did Harley's introduce any new products in Q3?", 
     'context': ("In Q3, Harley's made a significant impact with the introduction of **two new products** that have been well-received by the market. "
                 "The **Harley Davidson X1** is a cutting-edge motorcycle designed with advanced technology and performance enhancements, catering to the evolving needs of enthusiasts. "
                 "Alongside, the **Harley Davidson Pro Series** offers a range of high-performance accessories aimed at enhancing the riding experience. "
                 "These new products have been introduced in response to customer feedback and market trends, reflecting Harley's commitment to innovation and quality. "
                 "The product launches have been supported by comprehensive marketing efforts, including promotional events and digital campaigns, which have effectively generated excitement and increased consumer interest.")},
    
    {'title': "What was the impact of the new product launches on sales?", 
     'context': ("The recent product launches had a substantial impact on Harley's sales performance for Q3. The introduction of the **Harley Davidson X1** and the **Harley Davidson Pro Series** "
                 "contributed an additional **$2 million** in revenue, accounting for approximately **13%** of the total Q3 sales. "
                 "These new products not only boosted overall sales but also enhanced Harley's market position by attracting new customers and increasing repeat purchases. "
                 "The successful integration of these products into the company's existing lineup demonstrates Harley's ability to innovate and adapt to market demands. "
                 "Ongoing customer feedback and sales data will continue to inform product development and marketing strategies, ensuring that Harley's maintains its competitive edge and meets consumer expectations.")}
]





################################################################
#
# Here the \n in the text is treated as new line , so when you put it
# in the text it will create a new line automatically
#
################################################################




# create the object of the PDF
pdf = FPDF()
# you can specifie everything you want inside the object
# like:
# orientation (str): possible values are "portrait" (can be abbreviated "P") or "landscape" (can be abbreviated "L"). Default to "portrait".
# unit (str, int, float): possible values are "pt", "mm", "cm", "in", or a number. A point equals 1/72 of an inch, that is to say about 0.35 mm (an inch being 2.54 cm). This is a very common unit in typography; font sizes are expressed in this unit. If given a number, then it will be treated as the number of points per unit.  (eg. 72 = 1 in) Default to "mm".
# format (str): possible values are "a3", "a4", "a5", "letter", "legal" or a tuple (width, height) expressed in the given unit. Default to "a4".
# but i will not do add any thing , i want to make everything simple , to show you how comfirtoble you wil be when using FPDF2


pdf.add_page()
# pdf.set_font(family="Times", style="B", size=15) # bold
# pdf.set_font(family="Times", style="", size=10) # normal we are using this right now
# of course you can donwload fonts from google fonts an add them, using add_font , but i will use Times font


for i in company_info:
    title = i.get("title")
    context = i.get("context")

    # you have to chose the font that you want to write the text.
    pdf.set_font(family="Times", style="B", size=12)
    pdf.write(text=title) # this writes the text with auto break line \n
    pdf.ln() # this adds new line
    pdf.ln()

    # because the context you want it as normal we will change that to normal
    pdf.set_font(family="Times", style="", size=12)
    pdf.write(text=context)
    pdf.ln()
    pdf.ln()
    pdf.ln()
    pdf.ln()




# also it can make complex things like what you want , but it needs some work for example look at this final line
# i will write some of it bold and some if it normal
pdf.set_font(family="Times", style="", size=12)
pdf.write(text="first ")
pdf.write(text="second ")
pdf.set_font(family="Times", style="B", size=12)
pdf.write(text="third as bold ")
pdf.set_font(family="Times", style="", size=12)
pdf.write(text="fourth as ")
pdf.set_font(family="Times", style="B", size=12)
pdf.write(text="normal, but normal word is bold, hhhh.")




# now save the file
pdf.output("R_Student.pdf")
# if you do not add any name to output() it will give to you as bytes.

Thanks.
